# Handling the code base of a white label web based product

Tags: svn, deployment

We have developed a web based product that is on SVN, now a client has purchased it as a white label partnership, meaning he has got all the code but with his own brand name. Now problem is that if that client wants some custom logic that is different from our own product, how we can handle this situation. First solution is that we manually deploy all code files on his server, but in this case whenever we do a bug fix on our product we have to manually do that same change in his files.

Is there any better way of achieving this. My goal is whenever we fix a bug on our product it will automatically be integrated in client code, also the possibility to add custom logic only to the client code base.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is first to create a branch of you tag you have created before you delivered the source to the customer. Now apply all changes on the branch which are coming from the customer you can see all differences in the code between your released code and the changes of the customer.
After that make a new Tag.
You can now merge all bug fixes you've made on your code the branch of the customer and you can do a shipment from that branch and better before shipping make a tag.